# Android clean architecture - when to create a new repository?

Tags: android, clean-architecture

So I have an app that uses firebase for login and to store data also we use a firebase DB table.

The app has a login with google button so, if the google account is verified, I pass the account to firebase to store it in a db. After the account is created/fetched I store the users profile in a firebase DB table as well. So my question is about repositories using uncle bob's clean architecture approach.

Should I create a repository for google login and then one for profile? I mean, if we take a look at the usecases (interactors) there should be a `googleAPIInteractor` and a `firebaseInteractor` right? Or should I just create
a single interactor called `UserDataInteractor`? Do you see what I mean? I'm confused on how many repositories I should create. I think that each new repository would have its own interactor, 1:1 right?

Let's take a look at what I'm trying to achieve:

in the presenter code (assuming MVP architecture) I'd do this:

```
public class MyPresenter extends PresenterBase {


@inject someGoogleAPIInteractor i1;
@inject somefirebaseInteractorInteractor i2;

//both these repo's are using firebase so should i just use 1  repo instead ?

//.....

public void doLogin(String googleAccount){

    i1.fetchOrCreateGoogleLogin(,googleAccount,someSubscriber);
    //RXJava async call, not important. but it confirms google account and then in subscriber authenticates into firebase account for my app

}

public void getProfile(String firebaseAccount) {

    //this just gets stuff about the user like order history, name , etc    
    i2.getFirebaseProfile(firebaseAccount,someOtherSubscriber);    

}
```

the interactors i injected here would use their own repo's. one called

```
@inject someGoogleAPILoginRepository r1; //in i1
//and another in i2 called:
@inject someFirebaseProfileRepository r2;
```

i1 connects to google API to authenticate google account and then I will use i2 in the callback to create a profile.

So what I'm doing currently is that google API has a repo and firebase has a repo, and I have two separate interactors, is that acceptable? The thing is for the google repo, I'm not storing anything. I am just using it so I have an account to login to firebase with.

Comment: Did you managed to solve this?

Comment: it depends how your structuring your packages I would just keep a local repository like a data layer for each feature if you're doing feature modules or feature packages

Comment: I think you might be interested in reading this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-handle-firebase-authentication-in-clean-architecture-using-jetpack-compose-e9929c0e31f8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Repository' is mentioned in Clean Architecture is a design pattern and not an implementation.
It is applied for Data layer and works as a central place to manipulate your app's data from all sources (both remote or local).
A good practice is that you have a repository and its helper class in one place (a module or package).
There are several good examples from out there that you can take a look.
1. [Android10's sample](https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture)
2. [Ribot's guideline](https://github.com/ribot/android-guidelines/blob/master/architecture_guidelines/android_architecture.md)
3. [Google sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp-clean)